# Replace Objective-C function-like macros in bridging header file for Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, c-preprocessor

I am using Objective-C code from several iOS Cocoa Static Library projects in a Swift iOS Application project.

One of the Objective-C header files that is included in the bridging header file defines function-like macros for invoking a custom logging class.

```
#define LOGGER_DEBUG(FORMAT, ...)   [Logger logWithLevel:ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG   file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__ format:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__, nil]
#define LOGGER_ERR(FORMAT, ...)     [Logger logWithLevel:ASL_LEVEL_ERR     file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__ format:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__, nil]
#define LOGGER_INFO(FORMAT, ...)    [Logger logWithLevel:ASL_LEVEL_INFO    file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__ format:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__, nil]
#define LOGGER_WARNING(FORMAT, ...) [Logger logWithLevel:ASL_LEVEL_WARNING file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__ format:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__, nil]

#define LOGGER_ERR_ERROR(ERROR) [Logger logWithLevel:ASL_LEVEL_ERR file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__ format:(ERROR).description, nil]
```

Can I define equivalent Swift functions right inside the bridging header file and if so what would be the right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

What I did is to create a class method that returns the #define.

***Example:***

**.h file:**

```
#define LOGGER_DEBUG(FORMAT, ...)   [Logger logWithLevel:ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG   file:__FILE__ line:__LINE__ format:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__, nil]
+ (void)LoggerDebug:(NSString*)s;
```

**.m file:**

```
+ (void)LoggerDebug:(NSString*)s                { LOGGER_DEBUG(@"%@", s); }
```

**And in Swift:**

Since this is a class method you can now use it almost as you would the #define. If you change your #define macro - it will be reflected in the new method you created In Swift:

```
let size = YourClass.LoggerDebug("Test")
```

Comment: Does this scale up for the signatures in the example and could the definitions be put in the bridging header file (or somewhere else where any "client" of the static library project will see them)?

Comment: I updated the example code to fit the question - I hope it helps